# Higher Order Function invocation behavior is very confusing

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to invoke a function within a function which is not a big deal but for some reason i don't understand why i can't invoke a function through this logic:

```
function func1(futurefunc){
  futurefunc();
}

function func2(){
  return 3+3;
}

func(func2);
```

Now the result of the code above is undefined. However when I put: `func(alert)`, the alert argument is invoked. I don't understand why is the second case running and the first part is not printing the returned value which in this case would be 6.

However when I try the following:

```
function func1(futurefunc){
  return futurefunc();
}
```

the code seems to serve the proper value, which is 6 in this case. Any clear explanation. I hope I am not missing anything.

Comment: You should add a javascript tag if indeed that is the language you're using. Function call semantics depend on language.

Comment: You don't understand why your first case does not return anything even though you are missing the `return` statement? Why is that confusing?

Comment: @Tomalak It is was confusing because of parentheses, I thought it would just need that to call the function argument thus then since the function argument has return 3+3 then I thought that would be the returned value. I was learning about calling functions by adding parenthesis that I guess forgot the basics :)

Comment: Thank @Gene for the suggestion I forgot that!

Comment: `futurefunc()` is not "replaced" by `return 3+3`, if you were thinking something like that. It is "replaced" by `6`. So the result value will be there, but JS functions do not return values automatically.

Comment: @Tomalak no I was thinking since I am calling a function with parentheses which has return 3+3 value 6 I thought that would return since I called the function but apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case, func1 just invoke futurefunc() and doesn't `return` anything so `undefined` is printed.

When you passed, alert, alert is invoked then you see the dialog.

The second case, func1 invoke futurefunc and return its result, so 6 is printed.

There is nothing hard to understand here.

Comment: I was learning about function invocation within functions using parenthesis and I forgot that I always need the return keyword for the value to return. I thought that by invoking the function would be enough since within the function there is return 3+3, thought that would be enough to return the value. But it seems I am wrong. Thanks for the explanation